# Text overlap div

Tags: html

I have a comment box, if they enter long one word, "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"

the box will break(text out of div), i have used overflow:hidden but my friend want it to break like normal text.

Any idea how to fix ?

Comment: Describe break like normal? Do you want to limit the characters that can be entered? Or do you want it to return an invalid statement?

Comment: i want the text aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa, so follow the div box, if it too long, probably it go down to second row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for `overflow` to hide content that is larger than it's containers' dimensions, the container must have a set `width`. But even so, CSS doesn't break long words. (Except for IE, which has the `word-wrap: break-word` instruction. [Further reading](http://krijnhoetmer.nl/stuff/css/word-wrap-break-word/).)

If you're using some sort of server side processing (I assume you are), you could manipulate text content by breaking up long words at a preset length and thus avoid overflowing.

Comment: ah, i guess ill go with php wordwrap function.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use whatever server language you have to devise some way to break the string up. You could use a combination of regex (to check for long unbroken strings) and then combine it with some string split function in order to insert some newlines or something.